# Nodejs module: export async function

Tags: node.js

I am trying to upload images to cloudinary using a function I found in a tutorial.  I am uinsg type: module in nodejs and I cannot figure out how to confert it.  Here is the function:

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    if (!req.files || Object.values(req.files).flat().length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No files selected' });
    }
    let files = Object.values(req.files).flat();
    files.forEach((file) => {
      if (
        file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' &&
        file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' &&
        file.mimetype !== 'image/png' &&
        file.mimetype !== 'image/gif' &&
        file.mimetype !== 'image/webp'
      ) {
        removeTemp(file.tempFilePath);
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Unsupported format' });
      }
      if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 5) {
        removeTemp(file.tempFilePath);
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'File size is too large' });
      }
    });
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

const removeTemp = (path) => {
  fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
    if (err) throw new err();
  });
};
```

And here is the uploadRouter.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import { uploadImages } from '../controllers/upload.js';
import { authUser } from '../middleware/auth.js';
import { imageUpload } from '../middleware/imageUpload.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', authUser, imageUpload, uploadImages);

export default router;
```

I call it in server.js with app.use('/upload', UploadRoute);

I have tried change const 'fs' ... to import 'fs' from 'fs' and then module.exports = async... I have tried everything I can think of.  I have tried exports.imageUpload =  export const imageUpload... but nothing works.

Comment: What is your question? _"Nothing works"_ isn't a problem description

Comment: You're sending a response within a loop which will result in the infamous _"headers already sent"_ error

Comment: My question is hwo do I conver it to work when using "type": "module" and thing I've tried woks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if the file you are showing us is middleware/imageUpload.js and you are using esm modules, you should rewrite the first two lines of your module like this:

```
import fs from 'fs'
export const imageUpload = (req, res, next) => {
    //....
}
```

Anyway there are other problems in your code. You reply in a forEach loop; also you probably want to handle better async calls.